# p:commandButton not executing action method

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've dug around SO trying to solve this problem and keep on finding my way back to a post (which I can't seem to find again) where BalusC provided a list of likely problems, but I had already implemented the solutions to what problems seemed like they applied to me. The situation is that inside of my .xhtml file I have a Primefaces commandButton attempting to call a backing Bean method while setting some bean properties with f:setPropertyActionListener. However the bean method never gets called.

A troubling part of this is the page I am working on has buttons elsewhere using nearly identical code and these buttons work just fine.

Clicking on this button refreshes the page, but nothing else. Some relevant information: the button is inside of a ui:repeat, which is inside of another ui:repeat, which is inside of a p:dataGrid. The whole thing is contained inside of an h:form. There are two h:form tags on the page, however they are not nested. This button is inside the second form. The buttons in first form work fine. The backing bean is ViewScoped.

I am working with JSF 2.X and Facelets, as well as using Primefaces. My server is Apache Tomcat v7.0.47

Here is the Action Method:

```
public final String selectAnswerForRequest() {
    FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String navString = "";
    try {
        if (chosenAnswer != null && unansweredRequest != null && unansweredRequest.getResponse() != null) {
            brain.handleResponse(unansweredRequest.getResponse(), chosenAnswer, unansweredRequest);
            navString = "refresh";
        }
    } catch (BrainException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error adding answer", e);
        fCtx.addMessage(null, buildErrorMessage("hdrFailed", "txtErrorAddingAnswer"));
    }
    return navString;
}
```

Everything has getters and setters. I've tried changing the the action attribute to an actionListener and changed my action method to accept an event but it still didn't work. I've tried changing it from p: to h:. I've tried making it a commandLink, and an h:commandButton.

Edit: Here is is the whole .xhtml document in a more cleaned form:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:encode="http://envisage.com/jsf/encode"
template="/templates/twocolumn.xhtml">

<ui:param name="pageTitle" value="#{msgHome['pageTitle']}" />
<ui:param name="pageId" value="pg-home" />
<ui:param name="pageDesc" value="#{msgHome['pageDesc']}" />

<ui:define name="columnOne">

    <h2 class="section-title">
        <span class="label label-warning label-icon"><i
            class="eis-icon-recent"></i></span> #{msgHome['answeredTitle']}
    </h2>
    <div id="answered-questions" data-resize="trending-sidebar"
        data-min-resize="200">
        <h:form id="firstform" prependId="false">
            <p:dataGrid paginatorPosition="bottom" var="req"
                value="#{homeBean.answeredQuestions}" rows="5" columns="1"
                paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                id="renderTarget1">
                <p:column>
                    <section>
                        <div>
                            <dl>
                                <ui:repeat var="answer" value="#{req.response.answers}">
                                    <div>
                                        <p:commandButton update="@form, :growlForm:growl"
                                            ajax="false" value="#{msgHome['highlyBtn']}"
                                            action="#{homeBean.markAnswerAsHighlyUseful}">
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                target="#{homeBean.selectedAnswer}" value="#{answer}" />
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                target="#{homeBean.selectedRequest}" value="#{req}" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                        <p:commandButton update="@form, :growlForm:growl"
                                            ajax="false" value="#{msgHome['somewhatBtn']}"
                                            action="#{homeBean.markAnswerAsSomewhatUseful}">
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                target="#{homeBean.selectedAnswer}" value="#{answer}" />
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                target="#{homeBean.selectedRequest}" value="#{req}" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                        <p:commandButton update="@form, :growlForm:growl"
                                            ajax="false" value="#{msgHome['notBtn']}"
                                            action="#{homeBean.markAnswerAsNotUseful}">
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                target="#{homeBean.selectedAnswer}" value="#{answer}" />
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                target="#{homeBean.selectedRequest}" value="#{req}" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    </div>
                                    <p:separator />
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataGrid>
        </h:form>
    </div>


    <h2>
        <span class="label label-danger label-icon"><i
            class="eis-icon-question"></i></span> #{msgHome['unansweredTitle']}
    </h2>
    <div id="unanswered-questions" data-resize="moderators-sidebar"
        data-min-resize="140">
        <h:form id="secondForm" prependId="false">
            <p:dataGrid paginatorPosition="bottom" var="unansweredReq"
                value="#{homeBean.unansweredRequests}" rows="5" columns="1"
                paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                id="renderTarget2">
                <p:column>
                    <section>
                        <div>
                            <dl>
                                <p:separator />
                                <ui:repeat var="match"
                                    value="#{unansweredReq.matchingQuestions}">
                                    <ui:repeat var="answers" value="#{match.answers}">
                                        <div>
                                            <p:commandButton update="@form, :growlForm:growl"
                                                ajax="false" value="#{msgHome['acceptAnsBtn']}"
                                                action="#{homeBean.selectAnswerForRequest}" execute="@this">
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                    target="#{homeBean.chosenAnswer}" value="#{answers}" />
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                    target="#{homeBean.unansweredRequest}"
                                                    value="#{unansweredReq}" />
                                            </p:commandButton>
                                            <p:commandButton update="@form, :growlForm:growl"
                                                ajax="false" value="#{msgHome['removeAnsBtn']}"
                                                action="#{homeBean.removeAnswerFromRequest}"
                                                execute="@this">
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                    target="#{homeBean.chosenAnswer}" value="#{answers}" />
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                    target="#{homeBean.unansweredRequest}"
                                                    value="#{unansweredReq}" />
                                            </p:commandButton>
                                        </div>
                                        <p:separator />
                                    </ui:repeat>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataGrid>
        </h:form>
    </div>

    <h:form id="growlForm">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="5000"
            severity="info,warn,error" />
    </h:form>

    <h:messages />

</ui:define>
```

Edit 2: The most recent discovery was that after deleting the upper half of the .xhtml document (The whole first h:form), the buttons in the bottom half started working properly. I am currently attempting to use this knowledge to see where I can get.

Comment: would you post the full <form... Part of your xhtml? i mean the form and all code inside it

Comment: Okay, I didn't want to at first since it is somewhat large, I posted the half that contains my not-working buttons and then the half that contains working buttons.

Comment: Just copy code into another project, then trim down as much as possible code by removing tags/attributes/etc while the problem still exhibits. Once you come to that step the problem disappears, take a step back and then copypaste that whole code here. Surely tags like `<dd>` and attributes like `class="panel-body"` play no role in the problem at all. See also the introduction of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for hints on creating a good SSCCE.

Comment: Okay, I'm new to posting, so I appreciate any direction, I'll clean things up when I get a chance.

Comment: @KyleJennings have you confirmed that there are no validation/conversion/javascript errors by looking in your javascript console? Is the model being updated with the values you're attempting to set?

Comment: JS Console wasn't giving errors, but by looking at the elements we found that somehow both forms were being merged into one element so it must have created a conflict somewhere. For now we've put the whole thing inside one of h:form, which has resolved the issue, but somewhat inefficiently as now the whole thing will be refreshed upon a request instead of the relevant section.

Answer (score 0):

in your dataTable you use:

```
<p:dataGrid paginatorPosition="bottom" var="unansweredReq"
```

**var="unansweredReq"**

but in your :

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{homeBean.unansweredRequest}"
  value="#{unansweredreq}" />
```

**value="#{unansweredreq}"**

do you see the difference (**unansweredreq != unansweredReq**)? i guess jsf doesn't accept this. (i am not sure)

(**unansweredreq** used in many places in your code)

Comment: While I feel silly for missing that, I believe that is a more recent typo since I've changed around the command button several times. I changed it back to unansweredReq but the actions still isn't executed, I believe I had them properly spelled before.

Comment: @KyleJennings:  did you changed it in all places? check for similar other syntax errors!. Just for testing, remove the working form, and just let the problematic form and test it!

Comment: I never thought of trying that, after removing the upper half, my button successfully called the action method! So I guess it may have something to do with having multiple forms in one file. This sortof opened another can of worms, but at least it's progress, thanks for the idea.